# How can I create an Extended (custom) Property with EWS?

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have created a little demo application which is able to create a meeting request by using the Exchange WebService (EWS). I would also like to add some custom properties to this item but up to now I have only found examples which use the Exchange Managed API, which I won't use. There must be a way to create these properties by only using EWS...

Does anybody know how and can provide a little code example?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2008/04/uploading-eml-file-to-mailbox-with.html)